# Can Windows Server DNS Manager access websites on the internet, or only local records?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, dns, windows-server

In other words, is the list of records in DNS Manager the entire list, or is this just the extra records defined locally? If so, does it look at this list before searching the internet?

From experimenting with VirtualBox and a local DNS server, it seems I can access the internet. However, I am not sure exactly how this is occurring.

Comment: Windows Server DNS certainly handles outside websites.   See here for DNS forwarders  .... https://www.readandexecute.com/how-to/server-2016/dns/configure-dns-forwarders-windows-server-2016/

Answer (score 1):

The DNS Server role included with Windows Server indeed supports recursive queries and being used as a recursive resolver by clients – this is enabled by default, and that's most likely how *most* people use it, in combination with Active Directory.

Windows' DNS Server supports resolving hostnames both through asking other resolvers ("forwarders") and through directly making iterative queries starting from "root hints".

In other words, if there are any upstream DNS servers listed in the "Forwarders" tab of DNS Manager (*not* in the network adapter's settings), it'll use those – but if there aren't any, it'll still resolve Internet domains by directly talking to the root nameservers and following delegation chains.

If you want to disable this feature and restrict the server to only answering for locally-hosted zones, check the "Disable recursion" option in the "Advanced" tab.

Regardless of this option, locally hosted zones (i.e. zones that the server is authoritative for) *always* take priority over recursive lookups, in pretty much any DNS server software you'll find.

[image: Screenshot of the "Forwarders" tab, showing no upstream DNS servers configured.]
[image: Screenshot of the "Root Hints" tab, showing the default list of root servers and their IPv4 addresses.]
[image: Screenshot of the "Advanced" tab, showing a list of miscellaneous checkboxes and selections, one of them being "Disable recursion (also disables forwarders)".]